# inspecting jquery in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Getting my head around inspecting jquery/javascript in the browser (chrome)

I can see you can inspect attached scripts source tab, but just wondering for scripts that are sat on the actual page hardcoded in - can I inspect those the same in the source tab somehow ? as in inspect variable values, step in etc.

Thanks

Comment: There's plenty of documentation around for Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect inline scripts in the source tab in the same way. Simply navigate to the html file and you can view the source and place breakpoints as usual.

For example, see the inline source script used to make this [exploding canvas video](http://craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo.html)!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UyTG.jpg

Comment: thanks, also I'll delve into the docs and get my head around that particular area.

Comment: see comprehensive guide at [Chrome - Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)